# Arithmetic operations from XML in a shell

Tags: xml, shell, awk, sed

Maven test report is generating following output:

```xml
<testng-results ignored="3" total="22" passed="8" failed="11" skipped="0">
</testng-results>
```

Requirement is to divide passed test cases/total test cases (8/22) and pass the value to a variable.

Comment: Tried following so far
cat ./target/surefire-reports/testng-results.xml | egrep -e "testng-results" | awk  -F '=' '{ print "shell_var1="$3 "\n" "shell_var2="$4 }' | sed 's/[^0-9]*/ /g';

Comment: So [edit] the question to give a [mre].

Comment: don't place additional details (eg, the code you've tried) in a comment; instead, update the question with the additional details

Comment: At the first attempt to read OP post, was simple text, but when I try to edit, that was XML in fact. So this is not _that_ simple as manipulating strings. Most of the times, beginners use the wrong tools. So better add a good example in this special case. That's why I answered here.

Comment: BTW, if your XML document contains a namespace declaration like `xmlns="...something..."` upstream from where this data is, that can break some answers (particularly, it'll break the _most correct and robust_ answers, since they'll use tools that are syntax- and namespace-aware). Be sure you're giving folks enough information about context to be able to create something that's valid for your real document, not just for your 2-line sample.

Comment: (to provide context for that: `xmlns="https://example.com/foo"`, for example, means that your later `<testng-results` is really `<{https://example.com/foo}testng-results`; that kind of namespacing means you can have XML documents that merge different kinds of data without concern about namespace collisions).

Answer (score 3):

Using [`xidel`](https://github.com/benibela/xidel) and [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) query language:

```
xidel -e '//testng-results/@passed div //testng-results/@total' -s file.xml 
xidel -e '//testng-results/(@passed div @total)' -s file.xml
```

### Output

```
0.36363636363636365
```

---

#### You can also use `xmllint`:

```
xmllint --xpath '//testng-results/@passed div //testng-results/@total' file 
0.363636
```

#### or `xmlstarlet`:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m '//testng-results/@passed div //testng-results/@total' file 
0.363636363636364
```

---

#### So finally:

```
res=$(maven ... | xidel...)
echo "$res"
```

---

#### XPath's Arithmetic Operators

| Operator | Description | Example |
| --- | --- | --- |
| + | Addition | 6 + 4 |
| - | Subtraction | 6 - 4 |
| * | Multiplication | 6 * 4 |
| **div** | **Division** | 8 div 4 |
| = | Equal | price=9.80 |
| != | Not equal | price!=9.80 |
| < | Less than | price<9.80 |
| <= | Less than or equal to | price<=9.80 |
| > | Greater than | price>9.80 |
| >= | Greater than or equal to | price>=9.80 |
| mod | Modulus (division remainder) | 5 mod 2 |

Borrowed [here](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_operators.asp)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77039334/arithmetic-operation-from-a-test-report#comment135810595_77039334

Comment: Tried xidel in the shell step, however, doesn't look like it is available
sh: 10: xidel: not found

Comment: You have to install it by following the first link I gave (xidel)

Comment: @gopajitmalakar There isn't any standard tool with XML capabilities; you need to install one

Comment: You can try `xmllint` from my edited post, this is the most installed XML tool around. But `xidel` is better.

Comment: Tiny optimization for xmlstarlet: `xmlstarlet sel -t -m '/testng-results' -v '@passed div @total'`

Comment: It's not standard in the strict standards-body-approved definition, but I'd argue that the _most widely available_ XML-parsing tool out-of-the-box on modern UNIXy systems is probably a Python interpreter. :P

Comment: Or Perl @CharlesDuffy

Comment: @GillesQuénot, ...is that built into the stock interpreter now? It's been decades since I wrote anything significant in perl, but back in the day one had to install XML libraries separately, whereas in the Python world there are multiple (_sigh_) options "batteries-included".

Comment: You won the point ^^ It's named `corelist`: `corelist /XML/` : nothing relevant.

Comment: ruby has [rexml](https://ruby.github.io/rexml/doc/rexml/tutorial_rdoc.html) in its stdlib e.g. `ruby -r rexml/document -e 'tag = REXML::Document.new(ARGF).get_elements("//testng-results").first.attributes; p tag["passed"].to_f / tag["total"].to_f' file.xml`

Comment: @GillesQuénot With `xidel` you can do `//testng-results/(@passed div @total)`

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have access to a XML-centric tool then you have to do a bit of parsing.

Sample data:

```
$ cat test.xml
<some_stuff ignore this section> </some_stuff>
<testng-results ignored="3" total="22" passed="8" failed="11" skipped="0">
</testng-results> <more_stuff ignore this section, 2> </more_stuff>
```

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
    { for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {                                    # loop through space-delimited fields
               if ($i ==  "<testng-results" ) inblock=1        # start of "testng-results" block?
          else if ($i == "</testng-results>") exit             # if end of block then we have everything we need so skip to the END{...} block
          else if (inblock) {                                  # if we are in the "testng-results" block then ...
                  split($i,a,"\"")                             # split the field on double quotes and ...
                       if ($i ~ /^total=/ ) total  = a[2]      # save the 
                  else if ($i ~ /^passed=/) passed = a[2]      # desire values
               }
      }
    }
END { printf "%0.6f\n", (total==0 ? 0 : passed/total) }
' test.xml
```

This generates:

```
0.363636
```

Comment: Would not recommend parsing XML with regular expressions.

Comment: Same thing. Definitely a bad design. Especially for a beginner.